# Run Search on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

So I have this API call to Wikipedia which works on button click, but I want to search it on enter press as well. I have tried something like this but got stuck..any help appreciated.

```
$('#search').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $("#searchTerm").click();
    }
})
```

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ut88e0y3/

Comment: You just need to swap `searchTerm` and `search`. `search` is your button which needs to get clicked on enter of `searchTerm`

Comment: Ouch, ninja'ed. :P

Answer (score 2):

you should use keypress with the document like this:

```
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            if($('#search').is(':focus')){
                $('#searchTerm').click();
            }
        }
    });
```

see your example after edit here: https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/7j6h1jv7/

Comment: This could be a problem if you have more than one button.

Comment: This isn't the best solution.It will trigger the code even when I'm not focussing on the input field.

Comment: I can't have more than one button with the same ID, so it won't make any problem

Comment: @AhmedSalama, your function is triggering for the entire document, not just the button.

Comment: Eh, wouldn't it be simpler to just attach the event to the input?

Comment: I made edit on it so it will work only when I am focus the input https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/7j6h1jv7/2/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of listen each keypress, you can use `<form>` element and submit event. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hutrzvxp/).

Comment: @SatejS With a `form` and `submit` button, the form will also submit when pressing enter.

Answer (score 0):

You should attach the event to the `<input>`, not to the `<button>`.

```
$('#searchTerm').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $("#search").click();
    }
});
```

Or, if you prefer attaching to the document:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '#searchTerm', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $("#search").click();
    }
});
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/tbnexLd8/